Prove parallel vector has two directions
I have faced something confusing in my High School Add Math about vector recently.
A teacher tries to persuade me that parallel vectors = same direction. Because the textbook did the same thing in the questions it provided.
Is it true that we must not consider both directions (either same or opposite) in a pair of parallel vectors?
What my understanding is: if two vectors (Let say $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{CD}$) are parallel to each other, then it has two cases of directions:
Assume $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{CD}$ are equal in magnitude,

vector $\overrightarrow{AB}$ move in the same direction as $\overrightarrow{CD}$:$$\overrightarrow{AB} = \overrightarrow{CD}$$
A----->B = C----->D

vector $\overrightarrow{AB}$ move in the opposite direction as $\overrightarrow{CD}$:$$\overrightarrow{AB} = -\overrightarrow{CD}$$
A----->B = - C<-----D


and $\left|\overrightarrow{AB}\right|$ = AB because direction is ignored, $\left|\overrightarrow{AB}\right|$ is a scalar. Thus, a vector have cases of positive and negative direction (depends on which way you consider positive and vice versa). Parallel vectors don't necessarily mean that they move in same direction.
I've taken a few questions from my textbook to be attached here. My solution does not match entirely with the answer given in textbook. I think there is possibility that the textbook makes a mistake. Do parallel vectors mean same direction?






Edit 1: To fix the definition of parallel, I will attach a few definitions from different sources:

Euclid's Elements of Geometry (Parallel Postulate):

If a straight-line falling across two (other)
straight-lines makes internal angles on the same side
(of itself whose sum is) less than two right-angles, then
the two (other) straight-lines, being produced to infinity,
meet on that side (of the original straight-line) that the
(sum of the internal angles) is less than two right-angles
(and do not meet on the other side).

CueMath [Link]{https://www.cuemath.com/geometry/parallel-vectors/}:

The parallel vectors are vectors that have the same direction or exactly the opposite direction. i.e., for any vector a, the vector itself and its opposite vector -a are vectors that are always parallel to a.

Mathematical Proof:

We learn that, if $\overrightarrow{A}$ is parallel to $\overrightarrow{B}$, we can write the general equation relating $\overrightarrow{A}$ and $\overrightarrow{B}$ as $$\overrightarrow{A} = k\overrightarrow{B}$$ where if $$k > 0$$ $\overrightarrow{A}$ and $\overrightarrow{B}$ move parallelly in same direction
if $$k<0$$ $\overrightarrow{A}$ and $\overrightarrow{B}$ move parallelly in opposite direction
Thus, the general equation of parallel vector $$\overrightarrow{A} = k\overrightarrow{B}$$ proves parallel vectors can work in two directions. Because the equation holds true for any parallel vectors regarless direction and magnitude (scalar multiple). Parallel vectors can move in same or opposite direction, as long as they do not intersect each other at any point, thus angle between parallel vectors = $0^\circ$
In general,
Two vectors are parallel if they point in the same direction or in exactly opposite directions. Parallel vectors are always equidistant from each other, regardless of their magnitude.
Edit 2: 

Hope that somebody can check my solution for those questions. Please.

We don't say vectors are parallel, but collinear, meaning one is a multiple of the other. Afaik direction is defined as a nonzero vector in the first place. So two vectors $a,b$ have the same direction if $a=kb$, where $k >0$.

@AlvinL Isn't collinear lying on the same straight line? I'm sorry but in my case the vectors are not moving in a same straight line, but different straight lines that their difference of angle = $0^\circ$, thus I say them parallel

@AlvinL Yeah, and I understand that if k > 0 they are in the same direction, but if the direction is not specified, k could be k > 0 or k < 0, and this created two cases that I asked in the question.

When they point in the same direction the vectors are parallel, when they point in opposite direction we can call them anti-parralel

@Andrei -- That's what I learned at school :)

@Andrei -- TQ for you pointing out the idea of parallel and anti-parallel. Of course I agree with you about we have parallel and anti-parallel vectors. However, in the general sense of math, parallel vectors do not exclusively limit it to same direction (parallel) or opposite direction (anti-parallel). I've added definition about parallel vector in my question, from reputable sources, and mathematical proof is given.

If $\mathbf{u} = k \mathbf{v}$ I would call them parallel and would not restrict $k>0.$  Which would also suggest that the zero vector is parallel to all vectors.  On a side note, this is not how I would introduce vectors.

You're taking a vector to be something with two endpoints. In higher math, one endpoint is taken to be the origin. "Moving" vectors doesn't happen.

@user317176 -- Sure, the restriction of $k > 0$ simply means that vectors moving in same direction, whilst $k < 0$ in the opposite. However, if both $u$ and $v$ vectors are non-zero and parallel, $k \neq 0$. Imagine u is a vector moving in a certain direction such that $u > 0$ or $u < 0$, is it possible that you define it as the same as a zero vector, $u = 0(v) = 0$? Note that $0$ is not in the range, thus in this case, $k \neq 0$. The exception is it only applies when both vectors are non-zero and not parallel, and the only possible case for them to be the same is $0 = 0$.

@GerryMyerson -- Thanks for this reminder! I combed through your idea, and I am really fascinated. Btw, whether a vector has endpoints does not affect its direction? because the shift of position of a vector from the reference point, the origin, undergoes translation, for which the direction is preserved. I'm sure you are much much more than competent to fact-check my solution, why not post an answer so more people could be enlightened?

The zero vector is a thing.  In fact, it is the only thing that has to be in a vector space.  There is a flaw in the "magnitude and direction" introduction to vectors.  The zero vector has no magnitude and all directions.

@user317176 -- Sorry if I am mistaken, because I introduced myself to vector only recently. I understand zero vector as, it is like a single point with no length, width, or height, but this point is rotating relentlessly that it points to every direction. Thus, it has no magnitude but every possible direction. "magnitude and direction" approach does not fit in with zero vector. but in the case of my parallel vector, the vectors have to be non-zero, because the notation is non-zero vector $\overrightarrow{AB}$. thus, the case of "magnitude and direction" is certainly applicable.

I think of vectors as a fundamentally algebraic object that can be used to analyze geometric objects rather than as a geometric object in itself.  As for a vector space that contains only the zero vector, it is central to the study of linear algebra.

@user317176 -- yeah I have to apologise because I actually realise that I got your meaning wrong. A vector space still stands if it only has zero vector.

@user317176 -- would you like to try the questions? do the non-zero vector has positive and negative cases in the questions. if you're free. post your answers here because I am eager to progress further into this chapter, but not under the situation of carrying with me any wrong notion about vector.

Sense is also a vector property. When going A to B, it has a direction that is  opposite in sense as when going  B to A.

@Narasimham -- Yeah, exactly. In the questions I posted, the direction whether moving same or opposite is never mentioned. So am I correct of considering both cases (+ve and -ve)?

@Andrei You can distinguish parallel vectors from anti-parallel vectors, but many respectable authors write "parallel" in both cases.

While my answer to Question 4, out of context as it is in your posted question, would be the same as yours, in context it depends on exactly how your textbook defined "parallel vector." Please edit your question to show us the definition exactly as written in that same textbook. This is relevant information.

By the way, other than in a one-dimensional vector space, "positive direction" and "negative direction" have no meaning per se. What you can do is consider a particular vector as a reference vector and you then have sets of positive and negative multiples of that vector, but take a reference vector in a different direction and you get completely different sets of positive and negative multiples. You may find people contradict what you say because what you say is not what you wanted to say. Using words according to commonly understood definitions is important for communication.

@DavidK -- I am really grateful as somebody finally replies to my core problem. It's great to know about how my language doesn't convey what I meant though :P. I have edited the post to add the meagre definition my textbook provided, not sure if it will be helpful in this case.

@DavidK -- Yeah, that is exactly what I thought! The directions in parallel vectors are not defined unless stated explicitly in the question, which is something my textbook failed to do.

Interesting question. The definition in the textbook is faulty,
because if $\underset\sim{a} \neq \underset\sim0$ and $\underset\sim{b}=\underset\sim0$ (where $\underset\sim0$ is the zero vector) then the definition says $\underset\sim{a}$ and $\underset\sim{b}$ are not parallel. Compare the definition in ryang's answer.
But setting aside that flaw, which isn't relevant to Question 4, the definition supports your interpretation.
So according to the book's own definition,
$\overset\longrightarrow{VW} = \pm \frac72\overset\longrightarrow{XY}$,
that is, there are two possible ways $\overset\longrightarrow{VW}$ could be a multiple of $\overset\longrightarrow{XY}$, not just one.
If you need to convince someone else of this, it may help to trim the argument of any extraneous information. Really all you need to do is to cite the definition exactly as written in the textbook, and point out that $-\frac72$ is a constant.
Therefore, according to the definition, if
$\overset\longrightarrow{VW} = - \frac72\overset\longrightarrow{XY}$
then $\overset\longrightarrow{VW}$ is parallel to $\overset\longrightarrow{XY}$.

OMG, thank you very much! I have to show this to my teacher who exorcises me so much to get this notion out of my head and live on with the wrong answers.

To be fair to your teacher -- which I think is a good strategy for you when you want him to agree with you -- his statements are correct in a context where "parallel" requires that the constant $k$ be positive, as some other textbooks and publications require. Then in return you can ask that he be fair to you and recognize that you correctly applied the definition that is in the textbook you are using.






Rather, this is the definition that I'm used to:

Two vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are collinear (alternatively: parallel) iff $$\vec a=k\vec b\text{ for some real }k\quad\text{or}\quad\vec b=\vec0.$$
(In particular, two nonzero vectors being collinear/parallel means that they are parallel to the same line.)

Your textbook's definition is problematic: notice that it is at best ambiguous on whether $\vec b=\vec0$ is parallel to a unit vector $\vec a.$
This carelessness notwithstanding, your textbook's definition does consider parallel vectors to be a superset of antiparallel vectors—in agreement with the standard meaning of "parallel" vectors.

Thank you for your answer. Could you please check my solution for those questions posted above? I mean parallel has two kinds of cases, either two vectors being in same direction or two vectors being in opposite direction, isn't it?

@Awesome126 Why don’t you just interrogate the (carefully worded) definition that I gave? In particular, do you think “for some real $k$” includes the cases  of nonpositive $k?$ You can also use my definition to solve your posted exercises.

Really, I have no offense. I certainly read your definition carefully enough that I know $k$ can be positive or negative. Maybe I have word it wrong, my meaning is could you check the questions my textbook provided, to see if they are problematic by not considering $k$ being nonpositive. The second part of my previous reply is not directed to you. Anyway, I apologize on the ambiguity in my previous reply.

Thus, final conclusion is the textbook teaches the wrong definition. And provided wrong answer which goes against the wrong definition it set. My interesting textbook. Completely speechless.

about the PS, I just wanted to know if my textbook is wrong. but nobody looks at the example question I provided which a bit of upset me. though, I find them useful as well.

@Awesome126 The textbook's wrong definition is just a minor glitch that doesn't handle edge cases well. Isn't the main point (what you have been asking all along) that your textbook (and most authors) does agree with you that $\vec p$ and $(-\vec p)$ are parallel vectors? (None of this requires looking at your exercises.)

yeah, the textbook definition does agree with my solution. but its answers scheme goes against my solution which goes against its definition in turn. you must understand that the textbook writer is a PhD holder, when I am just a common high schooler, I am not confident enough to tell straight off that he is wrong. that's why I need higher-level professionals like y'all to reconfirm my idea.
